# Cartesian product as a collection of indexed families

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given an indexed family of sets $(X_i)_{i\in I}$, a canonical definition of Cartesian product is:
$$
\prod_{i \in I} X_i = \left\{f\ \Big|\ f: I \longrightarrow \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i\ \wedge (\forall i\in I)\big(f(i) \in X_i\big)\right\}
$$

I wonder if this definition is correct as well:
$$
\prod_{i \in I} X_i = \left\{t\ \Big|\ t=(x_i)_{i\in I}   \wedge (\forall i\in I)\big(x_i \in X_i\big)\right\}
$$

Setting $\mathcal{X}=\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i$, 
the domain of each family $t$ (in the second notation) is not  explicitly set, but values $t(i)$, that is $x_i$, should be in $X_i$ and so only those functions $t$ compatible with $\mathcal{X}$ are acceptable.
Also, the cardinality of $\mathsf{Rng} f$ (in the first notation) is usually smaller than the cardinality of $\mathcal{X}$ and the same as $I$. That is not possible for $t$, since families are 
[surjections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family#Mathematical_statement).
So each $t$ should have a distinct domain, with the cardinality of $I$.

## Update

I reply here to a comment regarding indexed families.
I define an indexed family as an alias for surjective function.

Given a surjective function:
\begin{align}
 x\colon I &\longrightarrow X \\
 i &\mapsto x_i = x(i),
\end{align}
it can be denoted also with: 
$$(x_i)_{i\in I}$$ 
The range of the function $x$ might be denoted with:
$$\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$$ 
 or
$\{ x_i \ \big|\ i \in I \} $. This is the standard definition I found in several books, e.g. Tourlakis, "Lectures in Logic and Set Theory" or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family#Mathematical_statement).

Comment: What does $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ mean? You refer to it as a “family” and as a function, and you say “families are surjections.” I think it’s safer to define things in terms of more commonly-understood objects, like functions (in the top definition).

Comment: Hi Antonio, the axiom of choice can be rewritten as "the Cartesian product of nonempty sets is a nonempty set itself." Hence, the first equality holds. The second equality is plainly odd.

Comment: @SteveKass please,  see the update on families

Comment: @WillM. The CP is a set  whose elements are functions from $I$ to the bigunion. The indexed families in the second notation are functions from $I$ to a non-specified range, but the condition $x_i \in X_i$ should work as an implicit definition of the range.

Comment: @antonio a formula $\{x \mid p(x)\}$ is _always_ assumed to be of the form $\{x \in S \mid p(x)\}$ where $S$ is a set. In other words, it is kind of a requirement of set theory that sets defined by "relations" are always subsets of a known set.

Comment: @WillM. Do you mean that both notations are wrong under non-naive set theory, or only the second?

Comment: @antonio I wouldn't say wrong, but one certainly assumes that if you define a set $A$ as $A = \{x \mid p(x)\}$ then there is an "underlying" space where $A$ is a subset from. Anyway, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t = (x_i)_{i \in I}$ already means that $t$ is a function defined on $I$. A family of sets indexed by $I$ **is** a function on $I$. The right codomain can be deduced.

Comment: So, I understand this means the second definition is valid.

Comment: @antonio sort of. The first one is much better, being more explicit.